# for crud operation should i generate components for every operation?

Tags: html, angular

want to use "crud" operations for courses. Like create, delete, update, read. Can I achieve this by one course component? I did generate course component. Designed "Add course form" in "course.component.html", now I am worried about where should write the code for "update course", "view course","delete course". I wish to make it simple & easy

Comment: You can do it all in one component, but it'll get messy quick. Have at least one component for listing where deleting can be handled as well if not too much logic, and one for create that can also be used to update (based on some flags). You may also look into Smart/Shell and Dumb/Presentation components to simplify this - yes, more components, but easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you write a CRUD service where you store all your CRUD operations

like

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CRUDCourseService {

    postCourse(params):Observable<any>{
        return this.http.post('pathtomyapi/postcourse', params);
    }
    ...
    getCourse()Observable<any>{
        return this.http.get('pathtomyapi/getcourse');
    }
}
```

then call it in your component like:

```
constructor(private crud:CRUDCourseService){}
...
getMyCourse(){
 this.crud.getCourse().subscribe(
     (data:any)=>console.log(data)
   );
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you are just focusing on the User interface it all depends what is indide the course.

you could

- add a global course management component where you can `add` `delete` the course (each course is one line)
- when you click from that component on a course's link you could access the course detail then `update` it and add also add a `delete` option

globally this means two components and a course service

this is not exactly what I've described you but the main idea is here
take a look at [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tour-of-heroes-example?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

**REFERENCE**:

[Angular Services](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4)

Comment: Thanks sir this is helpful ,but actually i want to know that for crud views , like add course form , delete course , update course ...

Comment: @SAADA82 Not sure to understand it all depends of your User Interface. If you have one different page for each opeartions or if it's a simple cross like for delete. I think my approach is the best I could give you. usually if you are doing a management system then each course is one line (so you `get` and can also `delete`)  then when you click on the course detail then you can `update`

Comment: Sir do you mean ? i have to generate 4 components for crud? and then inject service in each component to get rid of re writing the code in each component  for http requests,

Comment: Sir please suggest me any article to achieve this in single course component i will be thankful to you :-)

Comment: @SAADA82 did that answered your question?

Comment: Yes Sir :-) Thanks